# Gnosis Safe Contracts : Error deploying to custom Network

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, hardhat, evm, gnosis-safe

There is an error in deploying to custom network using deterministic deployment approach. The custom network is a evm based network. By adding PK and NODE_URL in the .env the code is expected to deploy all contracts in the custom network but I am facing the below error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAyow.jpg)

I am using hardhat to deploy the contracts https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts with the below params in .env.

```
# Used for custom network
NODE_URL="https://public-node-api.klaytnapi.com/v1/baobab"
PK="08bb64b0bb5d4baa180920c93e9820a6e10669e0b7576b8e88baf2959447d46a"
ETHERSCAN_API_KEY=""
# Use the Safe singleton factory for singleton deployment. This is required if EIP-155 is enforce on a chain.
CUSTOM_DETERMINISTIC_DEPLOYMENT="false"
```

When I `yarn deploy-all custom` below is the specific error

`deploying create2 deployer contract (at 0x4e59b44847b379578588920ca78fbf26c0b4956c) using deterministic deployment (https://github.com/Arachnid/deterministic-deployment-proxy)An unexpected error occurred:`

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with two checkpoints:

1. ["The chain needs to be fully compatible, i.e. support all opcodes used by the Safe contracts."](https://help.safe.global/en/articles/6227806-supported-networks)
2. You can request a new deployment at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory for [Deterministic Deployment Proxy](https://github.com/Arachnid/deterministic-deployment-proxy)